# Create a new time from hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: go, time

To make a long story short, the data I have access to is that I have Hours, Minutes, Seconds. I would like this to be converted to a time object (without a date). Is this possible in go?

Example:

```
Hours := 17
Minutes := 55
Seconds := 25.62
```

I would like to do something like

```
t := time.Parse(Hours, Minutes, Seconds) // hoping this reads 17:55:25.62
```

Everything I have found seems to require a date or a format that requires a date.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A moment in time has year, month, day, hour, minute, second, etc.  Are you asking for a duration like `time.Duration(hours * time.Hour + minutes * time.Minute + seconds * time.Second)`?

Comment: You might want to use [civil.Time](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/civil#Time) instead. It provides [civil.ParseTime](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/civil#ParseTime) just like what you need. Like @MuffinTop said, you shouldn't use Go's `time.Time` because it has year, month, etc..

Comment: "I would like this to be converted to a time object (without a date)" Would that do what you want? `type DatelessTime bool; func NewDatelessTime(h int, m int, s float64) bool { return h<m }` ? Probably not. Ask yourself what a "time object without date" would be and how it could be used. (Hint: a clockreading and basically unusable).

Answer (score 1):

> I would like this to be converted to a time object (without a date). Is this possible in go?

Not using the standard library. The `time` package offers two main data types: `Date`, which describes a point in time; and `Duration`, which describes an interval of time. There is no standard library representation of a time without a date component.

If you're truly asking if it's possible to represent such a thing in Go, the answer can only be "of course it is" - for example:

```
type JustTime struct {
    Hour int
    Minute int
    Second float
}
```

would do the trick, but whether that's useful depends entirely on your particular use case.